# Mysql UPDATE where distinct or unique

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a query to mass update a value (default_on) where the id_product is distinct.

```
UPDATE ps_product_attribute_shop
SET default_on=1
FROM ps_product_attribute_shop
JOIN
(
SELECT id_product
FROM 'ps_product_attribute_shop'
GROUP BY id_product
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
) AS FIRST_PRODUCT
ON FIRST.id_product = ps_product_attribute_shop.id_product
```

My db looks like:

```
   id | product_id | default_on
    ___________________________
    1 | 11238      | NULL
    2 | 11238      | NULL
    3 | 11238      | NULL  
    4 | 11252      | NULL
```

So as my above example **11238**  can be found multiple times and **11252** one time. So i need to update only one record from all of the **11238**`s found and the record 11252 also

But is not working :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is off.  It should be this:

```
UPDATE ps_product_attribute_shop t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT id_product, MIN(id) AS min_id
    FROM ps_product_attribute_shop
    GROUP BY id_product
) t2
    ON t1.id_product = t2.id_product AND
       t1.id         = t2.min_id
SET t1.default_on = 1
```

In addition to having the commands in the wrong order, you also put the table names in single quotes inside the subquery.  Single quotes in MySQL denotes a string literal.

**Update:**

To handle your revealed update logic, we can arbitrarily update the minimum `id` record for each product group.  The subquery in the above update identifies the records which should be updated.

Comment: Thanks, it works only fwhere the product_id is found single time.

Comment: Is this not the logic you intended?

Comment: i need also to update  default_on=1 where the product_id is found multiple times but only for one record(lastm first, doesnt matter)

Comment: I don't understand your logic.  _Update_ your question with sample data covering all edge cases, and then show what that table should look like after updating.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE ps_product_attribute_shop as p
SET default_on=1
WHERE p.id in (
  SELECT MIN(id)
  FROM ps_product_attribute_shop
  GROUP BY id_product
)
```